Does SFMC allow you to track scroll depth for eDMs?
I am needing to track scroll depth for our email marketing efforts. Is there a salesforce plug in that will help with this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No, it is not possible with SFMC, as it only provides you with a single tracking pixel, not being able to track engagement beyond opened/not-opened.
If you want to have more comprehensive insights, I will recommend looking into a 3rd party solution, such as e.g. Litmus Analytics.
